# How to log a GET request using postman nodesj with auth?

Tags: node.js, get, jwt, postman

very new to js/node js and this is largely a syntax question.

All i need to do is send a simple GET https request using an existing JWT token and print the results

I am using Postman.
From postman's [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-request#http-authentication) I was able to connect using the following:

```
var authtoken = 'Authorization: Bearer ' + token //token defined elsewhere
const request = require('postman-request');

var a = request.get('https://myurl/api').auth(null, null, true, authtoken);// I am using correct url
console.log(a);
```

Because I am new to the syntax - how do I get the postman response to print to console log. I am expecting a JSON response, do I need to set 
content type = JSON somewhere - if so how?

I used Postman's app - it connects and get's the correct data, now i need to do it from my app.js.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, postman acts as your app when making requests to the back-end. It doesn't matter if the route is accessed from postman or real app. `console.log` will output to the logs where the back-end runs. Regarding setting request's type to JSON, you can do so by clicking on `Body` tab and then `raw` radio. There you'll see a dropdown that lets you choose JSON.

Comment: What response did you get?

Comment: i solved it - the question was a syntax one and after trial, rip-hair-out, and error: the solution was to put the console(xx) before close paren, before .auth.